# Defining function to be run on every page load

Tags: javascript, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm building a songbook (with chords) with PhoneGap. Each song is stored in separate file, index is held in one of the files.

What I need is to be able to run some Javascript function every time a page is pushed. Meaning:

In `index.html` I have:

```
<li class="…" ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('page.html')">
<span class="topcoat-list__item__line-height">Some song</span>
</li>
```

What should I put where to run Javascript function when `page.html` is pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS Controller resolve this. For example,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-click="pushPage('page2.html')"><span>Some song</span></div>
</div>
```

and in app.js

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope) { 

    $scope.pushPage = function(pagename) {
        /* call some function */
        alert("OK");
        /* call some function end */

        $rootScope.ons.navigator.pushPage(pagename);
    }    
} );
```

Comment: I actually solved it with `ng-init` and separate Controller, but yours way works too, thanks!